# Amah, tefach, and pi

Tags: shiurim-measurements, mikvah-ritual-bath, mathematics, maseches-eruvin

I have a question on Eruvin 14a bottom which says that Shlomo's pool was round, had diameter of 10 amot and thickness 1 tefach, and circumference 30 amot (we learn from this that halachically `pi=3`).

However, next we read (Artscroll 14a4 right column): ["*but there is still the little bit of thickness...*" -- "*the circumference is calculated from within*"](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.14a.22?lang=bi). This seems to imply that amoraim knew that `pi>3` and thus they said that diameter of 10 amot was measured **outside** and the circumference of 30 amot was measured **inside**.

Thus

```
30 amot = 2 * pi * inner radius = 2 * pi * (5 amot - 1 tefach)
```

which implies

```
1 tefach ~ 0.225 amot
```

or

```
1 amah ~ 4.44 tefachim
```

and [*not*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_and_Talmudic_units_of_measurement) 6 tefachim.

What is my mistake?

Comment: I believe Rashi there says the Gemarra means "had diameter of 10 amot (**inside**)". pi = 3

Comment: @robev: the inside/outside is specifically to account for the error in the assumption of pi=3.

Comment: But you're asking from the gemarra, which assumes pi = 3 (not factually but halachically). If you're asking on those who suggest the verse doesn't assume pi = 3, I'd cite them and not the gemarra

Comment: the gemara implies that 1 amah ~ 4.44 tefachim; amoraim were quite aware that pi is **not** 3; they just assumed that it is 3 for halacha. if you assume pi=3, the thickness is 0,

Comment: Why is the thickness zero if the diameter and circumference are on the inside?

Comment: It would help if you quote the exact line of the Gemara which you believe implies that they were allowing for imprecision in the assumed value of pi

Comment: The gemara says that diameter is 10 and circumference is 30. and it answers, in response to a question that pi>3, that 10 is outside and 30 is inside. This implies that amah ~ 4.44 tefachim.

Comment: TTBOMK there is no question in the text of the Gemara there based on pi>3

Comment: As @JoelK said, you're not quoting the gemarra

Comment: @JoelK: 14a4 right column: "but there is still the little bit of thickness..." -- "the circumference is calculated from within"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116164/discussion-between-robev-and-sds).

Comment: Apparently the Ralbag understands the dimensions like you want to, and also holds an amah is 6 tefachim. Read [this](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol22Engelson.pdf).